# command not found: mssql on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-interface

I installed mssql using

npm install -g sql-cli

and it was installed succesfully.

The output after insallation:
`npm WARN deprecated sprintf@0.1.5: The sprintf package is deprecated in favor of sprintf-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.21.0/bin/mssql -> /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.21.0/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/bin/mssql

- sql-cli@0.6.2
  updated 1 package in 6.057s`

However, when I try to run

mssql -u sa -p myPassw0rd

I get an error that says
command not found: mssql on macOS

I also made sure that
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.21.0/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/bin/mssql is in my $PATH variable

What is the solution to this issue?

---

I am using

- npm v6.14.10
- node v12.21.0
- macOS Bug Sur 11.6

Comment: Not entirely sure about this, but should it be `/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.21.0/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/bin` on your path, without the mssql?

Comment: Yes this actually solved it! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding sql-cli your path, make sure to add the directory containing the executable rather than the executable itself.

In your case, add `/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.21.0/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/bin` to your path, rather than `/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.21.0/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/bin/mssql`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error and I've seen some tutorials in youtube getting the same message. Changing the path did not work for me. I checked the logs `docker logs <container_id>` and got the message:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password
> validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password
> policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password
> must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three
> of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base
> 10 digits, and Symbols

When I used a different password, it started to work correctly despite of the warnings.